# telegram bot does not work :Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-webhook

My telegram bot does not work! I did getWebhookInfo,

Response :

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "**secret**",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 10,
    "last_error_date": 1535344752,
    "last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found",
    "max_connections": 40
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your webserver sends the http status (previosly "Moved Temporarily") likely because the url to the script has changed...
check the url, maybe it has changed.
the bot api will not follow redirects of any kind (mainly because of security reasons)

Comment: There is no path change!

Comment: well... there is a redirect, which means you didn't provide the final location of your script to the api. maybe it's because of your webserver or hosting provider...